# Nlog 3.1 with Castle Windsor not logging

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, nlog

I'm trying to use NLog (3.1) with Windsor Castle Facility, but it's not working for me (no errors, nothing happens)

These are my steps so far:

1. Downloaded from Nuget: Castle Windsor NLog integration
2. Downloaded from Nuget: NLog Configuration
3. Updates nlog config like this:

   ```
   <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="d:\nlog.log"
           layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" />
   ```

   ```
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
   ```
4. Added Windsor Installer

   ```
    public class LoggingInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
           public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
           {
               container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.NLog).WithConfig("NLog.config"));
           }
   }
   ```

   Which I'm calling it (I've checked that a breakpoint in there is being hit.
5. Added the logger class like this:

   ```
   namespace WebApi.App_Start
   {
       public class MyLogger
       {
           private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

           public ILogger Logger
           {
               get { return logger; }
                set { logger = value; }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. Using it in a controller like this:

   ```
   new MyLogger().Logger.Info("New Request Created.");
   ```

But I don't see the file created.

Any step missing?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: If you use `new MyLogger()` then Windsor won't know about it and won't inject the Logger. So need to have all the `private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;` etc. code inside your controller class where you want to use the logger...

Comment: @nemesv. The problem was having the step 5 in the App_Code class instead of having it in the controller. Please create an answer with that so I can choose it as correct. BTW, Do you know why it doesn't work in the App_Code class? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `Logger` property to every class where you want to log something and the instances of the class has to be created/managed by Windsor.

So you need to add it to your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return logger; }
        set { logger = value; }
    }

    public ActionResult MyAction() 
    {
         Logger.Info("New Request Created.");
    }
}
```

It was not working with the `MyLogger` because that class was not managed/created by Windsor so it was not injected your `Logger` property. But because the controller isntances are created by Windsor and `ILogger` inejtion is wokring in them: [Windsor Tutorial - Part Five - Adding logging support](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx)