# Capturing log output from library using Castle Core Logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging, castle, white-framework

Currently depending on a library which utilizes the [Castle.Core Logging](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/tree/master/src/Castle.Core/Core/Logging) abstraction. I've dug through both that library's docs, and Castle's, and can't seem to find clear explanation of how to capture log output to pipe to our logging framework of choice (NLog, in this instance). I've also dug through a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297282/logging-with-castle-facilities-logging-and-log4net) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583610/nlog-3-1-with-castle-windsor-not-logging) which touch on the topic, but dismissed as not applicable to this situation.

It should be noted that NLog works fine for the rest of the application. No errors seen in the internal logs. Just no output from this third party library.

I see the [Castle.Core NLog integration](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/tree/master/src/Castle.Core/Core/Logging), but that looks to be something to be utilized by the library depending on Castle, not one depending on the library.

So is it possible to capture log output from this library? Or do I need to reach out to the project for support?

Comment: For additional context, the library in question is [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White). I'd have mentioned it in the body, but figured this question would apply to any library using Castle's logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the process hosting the library, it is your responsibility to tell Castle.Core.Log which log provider to use.

Configure NLog in your application, then register NLog as the Castle Log Provider [as explained in the documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/logging-facility.md) by calling
`container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.NLog)` when creating your container

For your library (white) you should provide the logger factory by either setting it on the `CoreAppXmlConfiguration` instance, or supply your own subclass instance when initializing the library's `Application` object.

See https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/Configuration/CoreAppXmlConfiguration.cs#L53

Comment: I tried the XML configuration approach, but didn't catch the note that code config is preferred. I'll give this a crack!

Comment: Remember that NLog also needs to be configured, so you can end-up with a bad NLog configuration that doesn't complain. Use `throwExceptions="true"` and `internalLogLevel="Debug"` in the `<nlog>` root tag of your `NLog.config` file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this project isn't using Castle Windsor, so no access to the container mentioned. And the library in question only uses Core.

Comment: Yeah, I should update the original to reflect that NLog is piping output just fine aside from capturing this library.

Comment: This ended up being the trick. I had to put it in an unexpected spot due to some runtime compiling, which is likely what was tripping up the XML approach as well. Thanks!